# Translate C++ code to Java with Mat object

Tags: java, c++, android-studio, opencv

I have working code in Visual Studio with C ++ on a watershed algorithm and I need to pass it to Android Studio. I have added the OpenCV library to the app and the simple operations work. Now, my problem is that when I want to pass the code to Java there is a specific line type that I don't know how to pass. The part of the code is:

```
cv::Mat markers(original.size(), CV_8U, cv::Scalar(-1));
//Rect(topleftcornerX, topleftcornerY, width, height);
//top rectangle
markers(Rect(0, 0, original.cols, 5)) = Scalar::all(1);
//bottom rectangle
markers(Rect(0, original.rows - 5, original.cols, 5)) = Scalar::all(1);
//left rectangle
markers(Rect(0, 0, 5, original.rows)) = Scalar::all(1);
//right rectangle
markers(Rect(original.cols - 5, 0, 5, original.rows)) = Scalar::all(1);
```

What would be the creation of the object would be something like this:

```
Mat markers = new Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(-1));
```

But the rest of the lines do not know how they would be transformed. Help please?

Comment: Do you know what those lines do in C++?  If not, start there to figure out what those lines accomplish.  Once you know that, pretend that C++ doesn't exist and implement the same thing in Java.

Comment: i know is adding a rect on markers, but i don't know how do that @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 0):

markers.submat(0, 0, original.cols, 5).setTo(new Scalar(1, 1, 1));

or

```
Imgproc.rectangle (
     markers,                    
     new Point(0, 0),        
     new Point( original.cols, 5),       
     new Scalar(1, 1, 1),     
     -1                          
  );
```

Comment: Thank you. I try it and compile, but when i try edit markers image don't happend anything. My image first is black, and would have a square on centre, but don't do it. Do you know why??

Comment: Try to draw one white rectangle to debug: Imgproc.rectangle (markers,new Point(0, 0),new Point( 10, 10),   new Scalar(255), -1);